# Protected members of same template class but different template types

Tags: c++, templates, protected

I have a `Matrix2d` template class and each `Matrix2d` object is a `std::vector` underneath the hood.  I often access the `std::vector` directly in the methods for speed and simplicity.  I came upon a problem when I tried to overload the `operator ==` to make it do an element-by-element comparison and make it return a `Matrix2d<bool>`.

```
template <class T>
class Matrix2d {
protected:
   std::vector<T> vec;

public:
    Matrix2d<bool> operator==(const Matrix2d<T>& rhs) const
    {
        Matrix2d<bool> mat(numRows, numCols);

        for (unsigned index=0; index<vec.size(); index++) {
            mat.vec[index] = vec[index] == rhs.vec[index];
        }
        return mat;
    }
};
```

The problem is that the `Matrix2d<T>` objects cannot access the protected members of `Matrix2d<bool>`.  Apparently the different template type makes the compiler consider it a different class, and therefore it can't access the protected members.  Is there a clean way of allowing `Matrix2d<T>` objects to access the protected members of `Matrix2d<bool>` objects?

P.S. Obviously I haven't included enough code to make this compilable, I was just trying to include the key elements.  If anyone wants compilable code, let me know.

Comment: Declaring `template<typename X> friend class Matrix2d<X>;` in the class should solve the problem.

Comment: you should always aim to include compilable code. It makes it easier for us to come up with a solution and **compile and verify it**. See what Jaron42 did. It really is not much effort to turn your example into a compilable minimal code. You should do this in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `matrix2d<bool>` and `matrix2d<int>` are unrelated type, even if they come from same template.

To allow each other to access to private member, you might add: `template <typename U> friend class Matrix2d;`.

You might do it only for `matrix2d<bool>`, but I suspect it would create too many duplications.

```
template <class T>
class Matrix2d {
protected:
   std::vector<T> vec;
   std::size_t numRows;
   std::size_t numCols;
public:
    template <typename U> friend class Matrix2d;

    Matrix2d(std::size_t numRows, std::size_t numCols);

    Matrix2d<bool> operator==(const Matrix2d<T>& rhs) const
    {
        Matrix2d<bool> mat(numRows, numCols);

        for (unsigned index=0; index<vec.size(); index++) {
            mat.vec[index] = vec[index] == rhs.vec[index];
        }
        return mat;
    }
};
```

Comment: Very nice solution.  Thank you.